# How to implement *ngIf/disabled on element of child component, predicated on parent component

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Parent component markup:

```
<full-screen-dialog-header (onClickPrimaryAction)="onClickSaveCustomer()"
  (primaryActionDisabled)="*ngIf=customerFormGroup.enabled && !customerFormGroup.valid">
</full-screen-dialog-header>
```

Child component:

```
export class FullScreenDialogHeaderComponent {

  @Input() primaryActionDisabled: Observable<boolean>;
  @Output() onClickPrimaryAction = new EventEmitter();

  public onClickPrimaryActionEvent($event) {
    this.onClickPrimaryAction.emit($event);
  }
}
```

Child markup

```
...
<button mat-button (click)="onClickPrimaryActionEvent($event)" 
[disabled]="primaryActionDisabled">{{primaryActionText}}</button>
...
```

I am trying to get `@Input() primaryActionDisabled: Observable<boolean>` to work.

My issue and expected behavior is:

- In Parent markup when I try simply `(primaryActionDisabled)="!customerFormGroup.valid"`- I expected the child's primaryActionDisabled to contain the observable value of the result of `!customerFormGroup.valid`, but its not.

Comment: why the value is not there because primaryActionDisabled is an input,
 so you have to write like `[primaryActionDisabled]="!customerFormGroup.valid"` note the square brackets and you can  make it just boolean, why observable?

Comment: I guess you need observable, otherwise change detection will not work properly.

Comment: Square brackets was it..  Missed the obvious one this question..  As for combining logic..  Will try [@Martin Adámek's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3665878/martin-ad%c3%a1mek) to address combining the 2 conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, when using `@Input` decorator, you should use `[primaryActionDisabled]` binding.

Then you need to pass observable there, not expression:

```
// in parent controller
primaryActionDisabled$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true); // disabled by default

// in parent template
<full-screen-dialog-header 
    (onClickPrimaryAction)="onClickSaveCustomer()"
    [primaryActionDisabled]="primaryActionDisabled$">
</full-screen-dialog-header>
```

Then you will need to call `primaryActionDisabled$.next(newBoolValue);` every time the value should change (so every time the expression `customerFormGroup.enabled && !customerFormGroup.valid` changes value). This will be again handled in your parent component.

Last thing, in your child component, use async pipe to work with the value of that observable:

```
<button mat-button 
        (click)="onClickPrimaryActionEvent($event)" 
        [disabled]="primaryActionDisabled | async">{{ primaryActionText }}</button>
```

Comment: Thanks..  Totally missed square bracket binding..  Was hoping I could pass an expression or otherwise handle it ''cleaner" in markup.  Will acecpt your answer after 6 min.

Comment: You could also pass a callback, but you need to bind it to the parent component if you want to use its variables, that way there will be no observables, but it will be probably less performant.